# Devise how to add signed in check in custom session controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying to use Devise's controller helper method signed_in? to check if a user already signed_in, if yes then I want to redirect to a specific page.

I have tried this, but the signed_in? method always return true, how can I make this work?

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
    redirect_to root_url 
  end

  def create
    if signed_in?(resource_name)
      redirect_to where_-_want_to_url
    else  
      resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")

      return sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
    end
  end

  def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, resource=nil)
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
    resource ||= resource_or_scope
    sign_in(scope, resource) unless warden.user(scope) == resource
    return render :json => {:success => true, :redirect => stored_location_for(scope) || after_sign_in_path_for(resource)}
  end

  def failure      
    return render :json => { :success => false }
  end

end
```

Comment: What do you want to use this for? Do you just want to display a different **homepage** depending on whether the user is logged in or not?

Comment: No, there is a situation that the login page is desplayed, but actually the user is already logged in. So I want do costume redirection

Answer (score 0):

You want that to live in the helper.

When a user signs-in, save the user as current_user

```
self.current_user = user
```

To check if the user is signed in you can use

```
def signed_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end
```

From Michael Hartl http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec:current_user

Edit:

Sorry, I just read the edit.  You wanted Devise's.

How does def 'signed_in?' looks like?

For the first implementation I recommend rolling your own to have a better understanding and makes you know where all the components are for fast customization.  Next roll you can implement other's methods.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `if user_signed_in?`

Now, I'm really not sure what you are trying to accomplish but I wouldn't define my routing like that in the controller. I'd do something like this:

```
# config/routes.rb
authenticated :user do
  root :to => where_I_want_to_url
end
root :to => 'welcome#index'
```