# Testing if a user just logged in with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, active-model-serializers

I want to include a user's `authentication_token` in my JSON response if they just logged in so that a consumer of my API can keep track of it and authenticate future requests. But I do not want to include the token otherwise. I am using Active Model Serializers to customize my JSON output:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email, :authentication_token

  def include_authentication_token?
    # what to put here?
  end
end
```

The Devise session controller uses `respond_with resource` where resource is the logged-in user, so by default it will use the UserSerializer. I could customize the Devise controller, but I would rather use `include_authentication_token?`. Is there some method in Devise that will return true when a User just logged in (i.e., the response is coming from Devise::SessionsController)?

Answer (score 0):

While the current Request is not automatically available within your subclass of `ActiveModel::Serializer`, you can easily pass it into the serializer's `options` hash by including it in your call to `UserSerializer.new`.

**If you explicitly create your serializer** like:

```
UserSerializer.new(@user, scope: current_user)
```

That means you can simply pass a second option called `request`:

```
UserSerializer.new(@user, scope: current_user, request: request)
```

From then on, you can access the current Request in your serializer by calling `options[:request]`. For example, to inspect the current controller inside `UserSerializer`, simply check the value of

```
options[:request].params[:controller]
```

If it comes up as `"devise/sessions"`, you're OK to include the token. Otherwise, **if you're using the standard Devise controllers** to handle sign-ins, you'll probably have to subclass `Devise::SessionsController` and reroute sign-ins to your new controller:

```
# app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource), request: request
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
devise_scope :user do
  post "sign_in" => "sessions#create", as: :user_session
end
```

Please note I haven't tested this yet. In reading [the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb#L323) for `ActionController::MimeResponds#respond_with`, it appears that any options given to `#respond_with` will be passed downward to the responder, which is hijacked by `ActionController::Serialization` and it looks like [the options are passed](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/lib/action_controller/serialization.rb#L54) all the way into the `resource`'s Serializer.

Good luck!

Comment: This would be a good solution, but I am wondering if I can do it without overwriting Devise. Your assumption that I'm instantiating the serializer myself is incorrect - the serializer is created when Devise::SessionsController calls `respond_with resource`, so I have no control over the parameters to the serializer's constructor.

Comment: Understood. I just updated my answer with another solution you can try. It's more annoying, but not too bad.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help you.

[- (Boolean) signed_in?(scope = nil)](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#signed_in?-instance_method)

And on stackoverflow  [Devise how to add signed in check in custom session controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844983/devise-how-to-add-signed-in-check-in-custom-session-controller)

Comment: This doesn't address the root problem: that the `UserSerializer` needs to somehow be aware of the current controller, not whether or not a User is signed in.